# Dynamic SQL showing SQL statement NULL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

While running this code:

```
DECLARE @strSelectQuery NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @strColumnList  NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @strTempTable   NVARCHAR(50),
        @strMainTable   NVARCHAR(50)

SET @strTempTable = 'TempdimRevenueCode'
SET @strMainTable = 'dimRevenueCode'
SET @strColumnList = 'DBID,Revenue_Code_ID,Revenue_Code_AltID,revenue_code,revenue_code_description,BeginUTCDateTime,EndUTCDateTime,IsCurrent'

SELECT @strSelectQuery = COALESCE(@strSelectQuery,'UNION ALL') + ' UNION ALL ' + CHAR(13) 
                             + ' SELECT '+CONVERT(VARCHAR,DBID) +' as ' + @strColumnList + CHAR(13) 
                             + ' FROM ['+ InstanceName +'].['+DBName+'].dbo.'+@strMainTable + CHAR(13)
                             + ' WHERE BeginUTCDateTime  > ' + CHAR(13)
                             +'      (SELECT ISNULL( MAX(BeginUTCDateTime) ,''1900-01-01'') FROM  '+@strMainTable +  ' WHERE DBID='+CONVERT(VARCHAR,DBID)+')'+CHAR(13) 
                             +' OR    EndUTCDateTime  > ' + CHAR(13)
                             +'      (SELECT ISNULL( MAX(BeginUTCDateTime) ,''1900-01-01'') FROM  '+@strMainTable +  ' WHERE DBID='+CONVERT(VARCHAR,DBID)+')'+CHAR(13) 
FROM adminODSDBDetails 
WHERE Active_TF = 1 and ClientProductName='GEMINI'

SELECT @strSelectQuery

EXECUTE sp_executesql   @strSelectQuery
```

When selecting the dynamic statement `(select @strSelectQuery)`, it is shown as `NULL`.

If I remove `ClientProductName='GEMINI'` from the dynamic code and select `@strSelectQuery`, it is printing a valid SQL statement.

Comment: Is there a record in the table adminODSDBDetails where ClientProductName='GEMINI'? Since you are adding strings it is enough that one of them is null to make it all NULL.I would recommend using ISNULL on each column from the table.

Comment: What results do you get from `SELECT * FROM adminODSDBDetails 
WHERE Active_TF = 1 and ClientProductName='GEMINI'`?

Comment: @ZoharPeled No result iam having actual result other than ClientProductName='GEMINI' in future it may come

Comment: Well, that's why your  @strSelectQuery is null...

Answer (score 1):

This can be caused by two factors:

- either additional condition in `where` causes the query to return no results (no records satisfy all condition with that one)
- or it returns record(s), but one of the value in that record is `null`, which makes whole statement evalute to `null`

so I suggest running query alone:

```
SELECT DBID,InstanceName,DBName
FROM adminODSDBDetails 
WHERE Active_TF = 1 and ClientProductName='GEMINI'
```

without assigning it to a variable and without extra text and see what is the reason.